# Routing params in angular

Tags: angular, parameters, routes

How can I load different component based on value of routing parameter ?
I want the logic to be written in routing module.

I tried but didn't find any thing on how to implement this in routing module.

Some thing like: 
if type is 'sum' -

```
[path: 'detail/:type', component: SumComponent]
```

else if type is 'sub' -

```
[path: 'detail/:type', component: SubComponent]
```

Comment: Why don't you simply do something like this? [path: 'detail/sum', component: SumComponent] [path: 'detail/sub', component: SubComponent]

Comment: then it will not be a routing params.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Avoiding typing out routes?

Comment: Yes, Also I need route params for some other actions as well. which will not be the case if hard code the type.

Answer (score 0):

If the type is not dynamic just set the type without param flag, for example:

```
[path: 'detail/sum', component: SumComponent]
[path: 'detail/sub', component: SubComponent]
```

Comment: He want to load with params from url

Comment: Is It mandatory use params? I don't understand why use params when you can type the routes

Comment: I need to get the route params on page refresh and perform some action.
If I will hard code the type then I have to get the url string and find the type.

Answer (score 0):

its impossible to do like that.

in your case you cant do something like this:

1.create another component.

2.add this to route.

```
[path: 'detail/:type', component: AnotherComponent]
```

3.in ngOnInit check type value and redirect to your component

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to do that otherwise u can do a child routing
[use child routing  here](https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/products/Z2lkOi8vbGVhcm5hYmxlL1Byb2R1Y3QvMzA3?ref_source=sitepoint&ref_medium=topnav&ref_campaign=component-routing-angular-router&ref_content=javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Yes you can achieve it, but with some dirty tricks. Like what I do it here.

Here how to do it:

First You need to create a component like I do here and named it as MainComponent:

> main.component.ts

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
 type: TypeOfDetails;
  typeOfDetail = TypeOfDetails;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.type = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('type') as TypeOfDetails;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

> main.components.html

```
<span [ngSwitch]="type">
  <p *ngSwitchCase="typeOfDetail.SUB">
    <app-sub></app-sub>
  </p>
  <p *ngSwitchCase="typeOfDetail.SUM">
    <app-sum></app-sum>
  </p>
  <p *ngSwitchDefault>
    <span>Sorry Not available the component</span>
  </p>
</span>
```

> Router Code

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'detail/:type',
    component: MainComponent
  }
];
```

Now you can pass your router param as well as `@Input()` So it will work as well.

Please let me know if you have any concern over the code.

Happy Coding :)

Here is the [StackBlitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5st6b) and here the [StackBlitz Demo](https://angular-f5st6b.stackblitz.io/detail/sub)